# CSS 3D Transforms - get screen coordinates of transformed element

Tags: css, css-transforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get screen position of CSS3-3d transformed elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025622/how-to-get-screen-position-of-css3-3d-transformed-elements)

Playing around with CSS 3D transforms, I'm in a situation where I would like to get hold of the screen coordinates of a transformed element ('s bounding box's corners) - is there any API which provides this functionality?

If there's no direct way to get them, I could compute them from the current `matrix3d` if I knew it. The transform applied typically looks something like

```
rotateY(40deg) translateZ(-450px) translateY(43.959403439996905px)
```

and this is what is returned when I read `element.style.webkitTransform`. However, Computed Style in the Chrome dev tools explicitly give it as e.g.

```
-webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.07660444431189782, 0, -0.06427876096865393, 0, 
0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.6427876096865393, 0, 0.7660444431189781, 0, 
-252.8460175498463, 39.09830093383789, -222.5671108990365, 1);
```

which makes me think that there might just be a way somewhere in there to get the whole matrix  programmatically even if the `transform` was not specified in that way.

This is only for fun and learning so anything Webkit/Chrome-specific is fine.